# how to make indent line for emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp

I encountered a little problem on my emacs:
I use my emacs to write lisp, but, you know, lisp's indent is so crazy. So how to insert the indent line for the emacs?

On the Internet, I get a paragraph elisp code for this function. I download it and save it as the ".el" file. And how should do after this. What should I write something in my ".emacs" file?

Thank you very much

Comment: Lisp indentation is not crazy. You are doing yourself a disservice by adopting a different convention. It takes some getting used to, but it has been stable for generations. Give it a couple of months, and I bet you will stop paying any attention to it.

Comment: Eh? Make sure you're in lisp-mode, press TAB for auto-indent (alternatively, re-bind \C-j to newline-and-indent). No extra code needed.

Answer (score 1):

Second question: Look the commentary in the ".el" file. There may be some snippets about installation.

Answer (score 1):

In the most basic case, you can load the Lisp code in an `.el` file from your `.emacs` using `load-file`:

```
(load-file "/path/to/downloaded.el")
```

Somewhat more portably, use `load` instead. Often, you want on-demand loading, though, using one or more of `auto-load-alist`, `mode-alist`, and `eval-after-load`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use the add-to-list 'load-path "......". And the (require '.....) to do it. Then it worked, but that is not what I had expected. There is only one indent-line in front of my function declaration. Other positions of indentation are still lacking the indent-line.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't have a .el file but a small piece of elisp code. Just write it down in your `.emacs` and reload it with `M-x eval-current-buffer`.